# String in wrong format when trying to convert to int32

Tags: int, format

I try to convert a string in my WPF application, whichs content is "5", to an int but get the error "Input string is in the wrong format". I already tried Convert.ToInt32 and Int32.Parse methods but both fail. Here is the code:

```
int inNumber;
inNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

I really don't understand this as it works fine at my office computer...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had the debugger not set up correctly. Code was fine.